# Calabash-ios Javascript Evaluation for CSS Attributes

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios

I'm wondering if there is a way to use `:stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` to fetch a specific css attribute from an element.

For instance, say I want to validate a background image and the css specifies `background-image: blue.png`.  I'm having trouble getting `:stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` to do anything other than the basic `innerHTML` example.

`document.getElementById` or `document.getElementsByClassName` yield an empty array.

Comment: Are there iframes involved?  If so, this gist might help point you in the right direction.  https://gist.github.com/jmoody/53276aa979c9cdc6a136

Comment: There are no iframes involved, it is a hybrid application created in Worklight.  My solution was to chat with the developers and take another route in identifying the correct image. :)

Comment: @tuggles, please write the answer to this question, since you have it now. Or, remove the question.